# Proving that a set is open and dense.

Tags: real-analysis

For $f\in C[a,b]$ and $s<t$ in $[a,b],$ let $m_{st}^f=(f(t)-f(s))/(t-s)$. Given such pairs $s<t$ and $u<v$ with $\{s,t\}\ne \{u,v\}$, let $U=\{ f\in C[a,b]:m_{st}^f\ne m_{uv}^f \}$. Prove that $U$ is open and dense in $C[a,b]$ with the metric $d(f,g)=\max |f-g|$.

So to show that $U$ is open I know that I need to find an $r>0$ such that when $\max|f-g|<r$ implies that $m^g_{st}\ne m^g_{uv}$.

I am given the hint to derive bounds for $|m^f_{st}-m^g_{st}|$ and $|m^f_{uv}-m^g_{uv}|$ in terms of $\max|f-g|$, $t-s$ and $v-u$.  Although I am not sure what the bounds would be or how they help me.

Then as far as density goes. Let $f\in U$ and let $r>0$. Now I need to derive a function $g$ such that $|g-f|<r$ and $m^g_{st}\ne m^g_{uv}$. I am given the hint that $v\notin \{s,t\}$ and that there is a functions $h\in C[a,b]$ that vanishes at $s,t$ and $u$ but not at $v$ and to try the function $g=f+\delta h$.

This is very confusing to me, I need help clarifying the question and how I can prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $U$ is open, one way is to write $U = F^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})$, where $F:C[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function. By definition of $U$, define 
$$\begin{split} 
F(f) &= m^f_{st} - m^f_{uv} \\
&= \frac{f(s) - f(t)}{s-t} - \frac{f(u)-f(v)}{u-v}.
\end{split} $$
Note that this is sum of four functions of the form $F_x(f) = f(x)$. This function $F_x$ is continuous, as 
$$|F_x(f) -F_x(g)| = |f(x) - g(x)|\le d(f,g).$$
Thus $F$ is also continuous and so $U$ is open.

To show that $U$ is dense in $C[a,b]$. Let $f\in C[a,b]$. Then if $f\in U$ we simply choose $g  =f$. If $f\notin U$, then $m^f_{st} = m^f_{uv}$. Since $\{s, t\} \neq \{u, v\}$, assume without loss of generality that $s\neq u$. Then there is a continuous function $h$ so that 
$$h(s) = h(t) = h(v) = 0,\ \ \ h(u) = 1.$$
(somthing like $h(x) = (x-s)(x-t)(x-v)$ would do). Then $g_\delta = f + \delta h\in U$ whenever $\delta \neq 0$. Choose $\delta \to 0$, $g_\delta \to f$. Thus $U$ is dense in $C[a,b]$.